# Help :- Removing Ubuntu using EasyBCD

Tags: uninstall

I am having windows 7 and ubuntu dualboot.Now, I want to remove ubuntu and I came across a method of using software EasyBCD (here is the link to refer it:-[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)) Now on checking Disk management, it shows C drive, E drive, Ubuntu partition (78.5GB) and An unallocated space (78.5 GB). Now, what should I do? Should I delete both unallocated space and ubuntu partition?
Also, the method says about deleting ubuntu swap partition which is not there in disk partition...

P.S- As I do not have windows cd and I dont want to make recovery cd, please dont suggest that method

Comment: Delete Ubuntu partition, it will be added to unallocated space. If you do not have swap listed it means that you did not create it in the first place. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for replying...U see, the ubuntu partition and unallocated space have same size(78.5 GB), so might have been created when i installed ubuntu.
Also, I cant add that unallocated space to C or E drive.aren't unallocated space used to expand drives?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it.I just had to delete ubuntu partition and use that unallocated space either as a new volume or use it to expand other drives...Done.
The method works like a charm.